# use find and replace with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

my html

```
<div id="sample-reminder">
    <div id="reminder_0000">
        <input type="text" name="val_0000" value="1">
    </div>
</div>
```

my code

```
rigaHtml = $('#sample-reminder').clone(); // i have to work on a clone of dom
rigaHtml.find('input[name^=val_]').val(99);
rigaHtml.html().replace(/0000/g, 987654321);
```

last command not replace my placeholder '0000'.
if i move replace() before find(), i cant' use find :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `.clone()` in this case:

```
var rigaHtml = $('#sample-reminder').html();
$(rigaHtml.replace(/0000/g, 987654321))
  .find('input[name^=val_]')
  .val(99)
  .appendTo('#container')
```

Where `'#container'` is the node you wish to add the modified HTML to.

Comment: I assumed there was a reason OP said `i have to work on a clone`. Seems you knew more than the rest regarding OPs intentions :) +1.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl This is because OP worked iteratively; at first a clone would be required, otherwise the `.val()` would update the sample div (which is hidden); the `.replace()` came later, but by that time a new approach was needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking to change the `id` property of `#reminder_0000` and the `name` property of `val_0000`, try this:

```
$rigaHtml = $('#sample-reminder').clone();
var $input = $("input", $rigaHtml);
var $div = $input("div", $rigaHtml);

$input.val(99).attr("name", $input.attr("name").replace(/0000/g, 987654321));
$div.attr("id", $div.attr("id").replace(/0000/g, 987654321));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the result back.

```
var html = rigaHtml.html().replace(/0000/g, 987654321);
rigaHtml.html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the returned value of `replace`. That should be written as:

```
rigaHtml.html(rigaHtml.html().replace(/0000/g, 987654321));
```

Even then, `rigaHtml` is not in the DOM because it's a clone of the original elements. So you still wouldn't see a visible change unless you put it back inside the DOM.